# Determination of a priori sample size to recruit for a fMRI study

Tags: r, size, sample

I'm planning to write a project in filed of Cognitive Neuroscience.
The problem I'm facing with, it as to determination of the maximum sample size units to recruit in order to carry out a double-stage study by using fMRI and EEG techniques. Is there any package in R that enables such calculation?

Comment: There are R packages (and simple functions) that will allow a sample size calculation to be performed.  But you will still need to provide some sort of intellectual input to use them: the size of the effect you wish to detect, the confidence with which you wish to detect it, the chance of a false positive that you are willing to permit, the type of data you will be analysing and the technique you will be using, to list but some.  Therefore, voting to close because of insufficient detail.

Comment: The problem is that I don't provide these details becuase that is the first time I am approaching to these. Therefore, I would just need some generic outlines to stick to in case of fMRI/EEG orr other neuroimaging technique order to decide the better the strategy and the paramteres to set. Can you provide any generic example below?